# vlan tagging is not working netplan -Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: networking, server, netplan, vlan, tagging

I have Ubuntu server 22.04 installed on VMware
I have connected it to a GNS3 topology to a Cisco router
The Cisco interface has subinterfaces with dot1q
The Linux server has 2 interfaces, one connected to the Windows machine and the second
connected to the GNS3 Cisco router.
I have configured the vlans in NETPLAN, but there is no connectivity between both computers (cisco-server)
When reviewing the communication with Wireshark, it is observed that the Cisco router does send tagged traffic.
but the Linux server sends it without a label so there is no communication since only Cisco is sending dot1q labels
and the server does not. I need the server to send its labeled packets.

I already had this configured but with a legacy version 14 server with `ifconfig` using dot1q subinterfaces and it works fine
but I'm trying to use a newer version of the server and I have this problem

```
root@rr:/etc/netplan# netplan status
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: vlan
     Online state: online
    DNS Addresses: 127.0.0.53 (stub)
       DNS Search: localdomain

●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8
                   ::1/128
           Routes: ::1 metric 256

●  2: ens33 ethernet UP (networkd: ens33)
      MAC Address: 00:0c:29:49:8c:16 (Intel Corporation)
        Addresses: 192.168.78.149/24 (dhcp)
                   fe80::20c:29ff:fe49:8c16/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.78.2
       DNS Search: localdomain
           Routes: default via 192.168.78.2 from 192.168.78.149 metric 100 (dhcp)
                   192.168.78.0/24 from 192.168.78.149 metric 100 (link)
                   192.168.78.2 from 192.168.78.149 metric 100 (dhcp, link)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256

●  3: ens34 ethernet UP (networkd: ens34)
      MAC Address: 00:0c:29:49:8c:20 (Intel Corporation)
        Addresses: fe80::20c:29ff:fe49:8c20/64 (link)
           Routes: fe80::/64 metric 256

●  4: vlan34.98 other UP (networkd: vlan34.98)
      MAC Address: 00:0c:29:49:8c:20
        Addresses: 172.26.1.131/27
                   fe80::20c:29ff:fe49:8c20/64 (link)
           Routes: 172.26.1.128/27 from 172.26.1.131 (link)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256


root@rr:/etc/netplan# cat 00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
    ens34:
      dhcp4: false
  version: 2
  vlans:
    vlan34.98:
     id: 98
     link: ens34
     addresses: [172.26.1.131/27]
root@rr:/etc/netplan#
```

[image: wireshark-screenshot]

Comment: FYI, Wireshark doesn't support showing VLAN tagged packets in its default setup, so I would *not* trust that Wireshark is showing info.  Have you *tested* if traffic works on the VLAN tagged interface, rather than relying solely on Wireshark?

Comment: Your setup looks fine. I'd look for the issue elsewhere.

Comment: Please, verify presence of your kernel module and 802.1Q package in system: `lsmod  | grep 8021q` and `dpkg -l | grep vlan`

Comment: I share the output of the commands.
Is there a missing configuration in netplan?
The server continues sending packets without a vlan tag and for that reason the communication fails.
Will it be related to the fact that the server is virtualized with vmware?

root@rr:/home/orion# lsmod  | grep 8021q
8021q                  36864  0
garp                   20480  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
root@rr:/home/orion# dpkg -l | grep vlan
ii  vlan                                  2.0.5ubuntu5                            all          ifupdown integration for vlan configuration

Comment: In the end I realized that it is a limitation of the vmware I use